# Filter array based on attributes in javascript/ react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, javascript-objects

Hi I need to filter the companies (array) that have same addresses and create an array like:

```
 [{address:uniqueaddress1,organization:[company1,company2]},
  {address:uniqueaddress2,organization:[company3,company4]
  .....]
```

I am using the following code:

```
 var organizations = [];
 var  dataPoints = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < companies.length; j++) {
     if (i === j) continue;
     if (companies[j].address === companies[i].address) {
        organizations.push(companies[j]);            
        companies[j].added = true;  //To mark it is added
    }
    dataPoints.push({address:companies[j].address, organizations: companies[j]});
   }   
 }
```

Original array:

```
  0:Object
  added:true
  address:"sample address 1"
  id:258
  latitude:90.90227
  longitude:12.538208
  name:"Company name 1"
  postalCode:"90450"
```

Comment: What's the original array?

Comment: @Ted edited question

Comment: Hold on a minute! Isn't this for CodeFights bot of uber? Haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to achieve this in a slightly nicer way (although you could also use this approach with an array of arrays as you've done already). You can also remove the inner loop for slightly better efficiency with larger result sets, by just adding as you go along rather than looping again for each address.

```
let original = [
    { address: '123 Example Street', id: 1 }, 
    { address: '123 Example Street', id: 2 },
    { address: '456 Example Street', id: 3 }
];

let grouped = new Map();

original.forEach(function(company) {

    let companies = grouped.get(company.address);

    // If we already have the key, then just push into the array.
    if (companies !== undefined) {
        companies.push(company);
    }
    else {
        // ...if not then create a new array.
        companies = [company];
    }

    grouped.set(company.address, companies);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I m using React project, can you please guide as to how to push companies to dataPoints?

Comment: Using React shouldn't make a difference in this case, you're only dealing with native JavaScript things here. The `grouped` `Map` in this example will contain the same data as you're putting into your `dataPoints` array.

Answer (score 0):

if you are comfortable in using `ES6` syntax then you could do this using `filter` and `map` methods. The code below does the filtering of array comapanies and the `map` method creates a temporary array, then we use the `indexOf` method to check if we can have the same object inside of our map.

```js
let companies = [{
  "added": true,
  "address": "sample address 1",
  "id": 258,
  "latitude": 90.90227,
  "longitude": 12.538208,
  "name": "Company name 1"
}, {
  "added": true,
  "address": "sample address 1",
  "id": 258,
  "latitude": 90.90227,
  "longitude": 12.538208,
  "name": "Company name 1"
}, {
  "added": true,
  "address": "sample address 2",
  "id": 258,
  "latitude": 90.90227,
  "longitude": 12.538208,
  "name": "Company name 1"
}, {
  "added": true,
  "address": "sample address 2",
  "id": 258,
  "latitude": 90.90227,
  "longitude": 12.538208,
  "name": "Company name 1"
}]

function uniqueArray(array, prop) {
  return array.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
  });
}
console.log(uniqueArray(companies, "address"))
```

[Credits](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/05/removing-duplicate-objects-array-property-name-javascript/)

Comment: This would be O(N²) though I think, right? `filter` will iterate through all of the items, and so will `map`?

Comment: @TomDavies yes `filter` and `map` will both iterate through all the items